# Spring Thymeleaf expression is not working

Tags: thymeleaf

Can anyone please point out the problem i am facing while passing values through context to a templateEngine please.

```
<img th:src="${serverURL}/support-images/logo.jpg" height="54" width="108" alt=""></img>
```

"${serverURL}" : supposed to give me the complete URL where my application is hosted. The error i am getting is "`Could not parse as expression: "${serverURL}/support-images/logo.jpg"`"

It make me realized something is wrong in the syntax but i could not follow the articles available. Can anyone please help!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mix literals and expressions in your attribute. You should probably write `<img th:src="${serverURL}+'/support-images/logo.jpg'" height="54" width="108" alt=""></img>` for it to work better. See the [examples](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax) in the documentation.

You may also want to read about the [link URL](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls) feature in Thymeleaf (`@{}` notation) that can assist when building URLs.